# Client/Server application with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, client-server

I have a problem in my VB.NET server/client chat application.

The problem happens when I send some information from the client application to the server application. I successfully established the connection and sent a message, but instead of showing that message, it's showing the name of my form server.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Server As TCPControl

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Server.IsListening = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Server = New TCPControl   ' fires new sub
        txtChat.Text = " :: SERVER STARTED :: " & vbCrLf

        AddHandler Server.MessageRecived, AddressOf OnLineRecived
    End Sub

    'da se uspijesno prenesu informacije na kontrolu 
    Private Delegate Sub UpdateTextDelegate(ByVal tb As TextBox, ByVal txt As String)

    'UPDATE TEXTBOX
    Private Sub UpdateText(ByVal tb As TextBox, ByVal txt As String)

        If tb.InvokeRequired Then   'HERE I SEE MY MESSAGE FROM CLIENT APLICATION
            tb.Invoke(New UpdateTextDelegate(AddressOf UpdateText), New Object() {tb, txt})
        Else
            If txt IsNot Nothing Then tb.AppendText(Text & vbCrLf)     
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnLineRecived(ByVal sender As TCPControl, ByVal data As String)
        UpdateText(txtChat, data)   'HERE I SEE MY MESSAGE FROM CLIENT APLICATION
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TCPControl
    Public Event MessageRecived(ByVal sender As TCPControl, ByVal data As String)

    'SERVER CONFIG
    Public ServerIp As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.108")
    Public ServerPort As Integer = 46555
    Public Server As TcpListener

    Private CommThread As Thread
    Public IsListening As Boolean = True

    'CLIENTS (samo ce prihvatiti jednog klijenta)
    Private Client As TcpClient
    Private ClientData As StreamReader

    Public Sub New()
        Server = New TcpListener(ServerIp, ServerPort)
        Server.Start()

        CommThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
        CommThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Listening()
        ' CREATE LISTENAR LOOP
        Do Until IsListening = False
            ' ACCEPT INCOMING CONNECTIONS
            If Server.Pending = True Then
                Client = Server.AcceptTcpClient
                ClientData = New StreamReader(Client.GetStream)
            End If

            'RAISE EVANT FOR INCOMING MESSAGES
            Try
                RaiseEvent MessageRecived(Me, ClientData.ReadLine)     ' now is displying the name of server form
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            'REDUCE CPU USAGE
            Thread.Sleep(100)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It is a typo: `If txt IsNot Nothing Then tb.AppendText(txt & vbCrLf)` It doesn't give you error because Text is referring to the property Text of your form (in other words the Caption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error when you update client TextBox on `UpdateText`.

```
If tb.InvokeRequired Then
    tb.Invoke(New UpdateTextDelegate(AddressOf UpdateText), New Object() {tb, txt})
Else
    If txt IsNot Nothing Then tb.AppendText(Text & vbCrLf) ' Here
End If
```

Change `Text` with `txt`.

```
If txt IsNot Nothing Then tb.AppendText(txt & vbCrLf)
```